# How do you say (someone) has (object)?

Tags: particles, possession

Basically I'm going through the が　ある / が　いる grammar - is it okay to say (person) に (object) が　ある/いる?, e.g. Michiko-san に　お金　が　あります (Michio san has money)

I guess I'm using it like you might say (Location) に (object) が ある e.g. "there is a lamp in that house" - does (person) need a different particle in the example I gave above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use に to indicate the owner of the object, as you did in your example.

It is also used in various combinations with は.

> みちこさん**に**お金があります
>   みちこさん**は**お金があります
>   みちこさん**には**お金があります

All of these are possible to mean "Michiko has money", but I think the last two usually sound better than the first.